# How can I programmatically create an user account and trigger an activation email?

Tags: 8, users, emails

I developed custom module to create users.

And I setup config account setting "Require email verification" to "Require a verification email, but let users set their password directly on the registration form" using the [User registration password](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_registrationpassword) module.

When registering via default forms it is works fine (email verification sent to user). But when I created user via custom module API the email verification doesn't send to user.

This is my code:

```php
$language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
$user = User::create();
$user->setPassword($data->password);
$user->enforceIsNew();
$user->setEmail($data->email);
$user->setUsername($data->nama_ibu);
$user->set('init', $data->email);
$user->set('status', 0);
$user->set('langcode', $language);
$user->set('preferred_langcode', $language);
$user->set('preferred_admin_langcode', $language);
$user->set('langcode', $language);
$user->set("field_name", $data->nama_ibu);
$user->set("field_dob", $data->dob_year . '-' . $data->dob_month . '-' . $data->dob_date);
$user->set("field_phone", $data->phone);
// $user->activate();
$result = $user->save();

_user_mail_notify('register_no_approval_required', $user);
```

Comment: You can't create anonymous users. Anonymous users are guests on your site. With no account. Regular non-logged-in visitors. What's that `_user_mail_notify` function? Where is it coming from? What does it do exactly and how? Please update your question. Many thanks

Comment: @leymannx: _user_mail_notify() is a normal core Drupal function. Yes, even in D9. See the API docs.

Comment: @leymannx thank you for fixing my question...
i called `_user_mail_notify` on my custom module and reference to core `user.module`.
I saw this code and replicate from `core/modules/user/src/RegisterForm.php`.
I don't know this code is work or not. I think its does't work, because when i remove this code and i replace with some code for updated user status to 1 after saving data first time the email has been send. is there any other solution for sending an email activation link on custom module?

Comment: Code is working - I have checked, except custom fields. So check: 1. email in site is working 2. spam folder in your mail. 3. errors or warnings on your code.